# Blazor-Server how to create ValueExpression with dynamic linq

Tags: c#, linq, blazor-server-side

I would like to wrap the Blazor inputs in a separate component in my blazor-server-side app:

*FormField.razor:*

```
@using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.Forms
@typeparam TValue
<div class="field">
    <label class="label" for="@Id">@Label</label>
    <div class="control">  
            @Input
    </div>
</div>
```

*FormField.razor.cs:*

```
public partial class FormField<TValue>
{

    [Parameter] public string Id { get; set; }
    [Parameter] public string Label { get; set; }
    [Parameter] public TValue Value { get; set; }
    [Parameter] public EventCallback<TValue> ValueChanged { get; set; }

    private RenderFragment Input { get; set; }


    protected override void OnInitialized()
    {
        Input = BuildInput();
        base.OnInitialized();
    }

    private Type GetInputType()
    {
        var tValueType = typeof(TValue);

        if (tValueType == typeof(bool))
        {
            return typeof(InputCheckbox);
        }

        if (tValueType == typeof(int) || tValueType == typeof(long) || tValueType == typeof(short) || tValueType == typeof(float) || tValueType == typeof(double) || tValueType == typeof(decimal))
        {
            return typeof(InputNumber<TValue>);
        }

        if (tValueType == typeof(DateTime) || tValueType == typeof(DateTimeOffset))
        {
            return typeof(InputDate<TValue>);
        }

        return typeof(InputText);
    }

    private RenderFragment BuildInput()
    {
        var propInfo = this.GetType().GetProperty(nameof(Value));
        var expressionBody = Expression.Property(Expression.Constant(Value, typeof(TValue)), propInfo);

        // another try:
        //var parameter = Expression.Parameter(typeof(TValue));
        //var expressionBody = Expression.Property(parameter, nameof(Value));

        var valueExpression = Expression.Lambda(typeof(Func<TValue>), expressionBody);
        return builder =>
        {
            builder.OpenComponent(0, GetInputType());
            builder.AddAttribute(1, "Value", Value);
            builder.AddAttribute(2, "ValueChanged", ValueChanged);
            builder.AddAttribute(3, "ValueExpression", valueExpression);
            builder.AddAttribute(4, "id", Id);
            builder.AddAttribute(5, "class", "input");
            builder.CloseComponent();
        };
    }
}
```

As soon as the 'BuildInput' method is executed, an exception occurs in the 'expressionBody' step:

```
System.ArgumentException: Property 'System.DateTime Value' is not defined for type 'System.DateTime' (Parameter 'property')
```

a similar exception occurs when I try the commented code:

```
 System.ArgumentException: Instance property 'Value' is not defined for type 'System.DateTime' (Parameter 'propertyName')
```

So how can I dynamically generate a valid ValueExpression so that my Input works?

Comment: `expressionBody = Expression.Constant(Value);` -  looks like this is all that you need. No properties should be used.

Comment: have you figured it out ? im building something similar.. can you post some working example ? regards